# could not determine type for: com.model.User, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(user)]

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Although this question asked many times and I have already used all the suggestion but still I am getting this error. 
could not determine type for: com.model.User, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(user)]
and tn

hibernate.cfg.xml configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">



<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name= "CONNECTION.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/covoiturage</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>



    <property name="hibernate CONNECTION.pool_size">1</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
 <mapping class="com.model.Messagerie"/>
    <mapping class="com.model.Trajet"/>
    <mapping class="com.model.User"/>
    <mapping class="com.model.Voiture"/>


   </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="User")
public class User{

    @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="iduser")
    private int iduser;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idvoiture", nullable=false)
    private Voiture voit;
             *
             *
             *
             *
    public Voiture getVoiture() {
        return voit;
    }

    public void setVoiture(Voiture voiture) {
        this.voit = voiture;
    }


}
```

Voiture.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Voiture")
public class Voiture{

    @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="idvoiture")
    private int idvoiture;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "voit", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<User> listeUsers;
             *
             *
             *
public List<User> getListeUsers() {
        return listeUsers;
    }

    public void setListeUsers(List<User> listeUsers) {
        this.listeUsers = listeUsers;
    }
```

Comment: try using `@Table(name = "Users")` instead of `@Table(name = "User")`

Comment: i try it but the probleme is in this instruction              @OneToMany(mappedBy = "voit", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 private List<User> listeUsers;

Answer (score 0):

Whenever You don't Mention @onetoone(or any Mappings) Annotations at Entity Class, as well as that Entity Class Mapped in the configuration file or Utility file, Then this Error - "could not determine type for: com.model" Error will Occurr.

Error name - [org.hibernate.mapping.Column()]

Solution - Use @onetoone(or any Mappings), in source Entity class...

Thankyou!